# Unable to create Sidebar using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Book Fair</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "page">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="name">
                <button class="sidebarbtn" onclick="Menu()">
                    &#x2192;
                </button>
                <a href="book fair.html"> Book Fair</a>
            </div>
            <div class="left-side">
                <a href="#">Cart</a>
                <a href ="#">SignIn</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Side bar -->
        <aside class = "sidebarcon">
            <h3>Book Categories</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Romance</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        </main>
        
    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script>
        function Menu(){
            document.querySelector(".sidebarbtn").classList.add(".sidebarcon.open");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
.sidebarbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    color: brown;
    padding: 10px;
    background: none;
}

.sidebarcon{
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(-10rem);
    width: 10rem;
}

.sidebarcon.open{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

I have create a navbar, from that I wanted to create a sidebar. I suspect there is a problem with my JS script but I am unable to find the fault. I am trying to use the classList.add() method here. I have searched everywhere and tried all possibility.

Comment: you should not add className with dot.
try 
document.querySelector(".sidebarbtn").classList.add("sidebarcon");
document.querySelector(".sidebarbtn").classList.add("open");
this should work

Answer (score 1):

Unlike querying a selector, when you add a style class to an element using `classList.add()` you do not include the leading `.`.  Additionally, in this case, you want to add the opening style class to the sidebar, not the button.

Try something like this:

```css
.sidebarbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    color: brown;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.sidebarcon{
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(-10rem);
    width: 10rem;
    background-color: red;
}

.openSidebar{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
ML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Book Fair</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "page">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="name">
                <button class="sidebarbtn" onclick="Menu()">
                    &#x2192;
                </button>
                <a href="book fair.html"> Book Fair</a>
            </div>
            <div class="left-side">
                <a href="#">Cart</a>
                <a href ="#">SignIn</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Side bar -->
        <aside class = "sidebarcon">
            <h3>Book Categories</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Romance</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        
    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script>
        function Menu(){
            document.querySelector(".sidebarcon").classList.add("openSidebar");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```